# nuget - determine the project type before they try to install my package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

how can I determine the project type before they try to install my package. I wanna show them a cancelation message if the project type is not and MVC application and cancel the installation process?

do I need to add a ps1 script file into tools folder of my package? if so, what should I write inside this script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it seems that pre-installation checks for aborting the install is not possible. See the answer from David Fowler [here](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/245635).

Scott Hanselman has [an example](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingANuGetPackageIn7EasyStepsPlusUsingNuGetToIntegrateASPNETMVC3IntoExistingWebFormsApplications.aspx) on how to check pre-requisites using the install.ps1 script. He also mentions that it's currently not possible to stop the installation process, but that "In the future there will likely be a pre-install or a dependency check".